# What are some examples of algebras that satisfy the hypothesis of Stone's theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, algebras, function-spaces

I have just learned Stone's theorem (at least as is written in baby Rudin):

> Let $\mathscr{A}$ be an algebra of real continuous functions on a compact set $K$. If $\mathscr{A}$ separates points on $K$ and if $\mathscr{A}$ vanishes at no point of $K$, then the uniform closure $\mathscr{B}$ of $\mathscr{A}$ consists of all real continuous functions on $K$.

I was wondering about concrete examples of algebras $\mathscr{A}$ of real continuous functions on compact sets that separate points and do not vanish. Obviously one choice is the set of all polynomials on $K$, and this case yields Weierstrass' theorem. What are some other examples? Are there nice examples when $K$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: What does "$\mathcal{A}$ vanishes at no point in $K$" mean - that there is no point in $K$ where *all* the functions in $\mathcal{A}$ vanish simultaneously?

Comment: That is correct @NoahSchweber

Comment: Trig functions give rise to such a family - e.g. the set of (restrictions to $K$ of) all functions of the form $x\mapsto \sin(ax+b)$ for $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$.